# First Run of Script - My Function ExecuteSqlQuery is not recognized as the name of a function,

Tags: sql, powershell

when I run the script the first time - it fails with the error below and every subsequent runs of the script work as expected.  The script calls the function in this line:
$1_resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery

and the second attempt makes the server and database connection to run the query correctly:
function ExecuteSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {

ExecuteSqlQuery : The term 'ExecuteSqlQuery' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\figuerdsa\Documents\before22821.ps1:7 char:23

- $1_resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery
- ```
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ExecuteSqlQuery:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

  [string] $Server= "Server"
  [string] $Database = "mvTest"
  [string] $UserSqlQuery= $("select m.created_date, m.additional_data as ReasonDown from aeroscout.mv_audit m where m.created_date >= '2020-01-18' and m.additional_data like '%remainingCapacity={`"o`":`"3.5`",`"n`":`"3.0`"};batteryReplacementDate={`"o`":`"2020-02-29%'")

  $1_resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery
  Start-Sleep 5

  $2_resultsDataTable = ExecuteSqlQuery $Server $Database $UserSqlQuery

  ## executes a query and populates the $datatable with the data

  function ExecuteSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {

  ```
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';Integrated Security=True;"
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
  ```

  If ($Reader.HasRows) {

  ```
          $obj = $Reader | foreach {
    $row = $_;  
    new-object psObject -Property @{ 
        CreateDate = $row.Item("created_date")
        ReasonDown = $row.Item("ReasonDown")
         }

        #Write-Output $obj
      }
   }
     return $obj
    $Connection.Close()
  ```

  $Connection.Dispose()

  }

  $fields = "created_date", "ReasonDown"
  $exportObject=@()
  $exportObject = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $1_resultsDataTable -DifferenceObject $1_resultsDataTable -IncludeEqual -Property $fields -PassThru | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "==" }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not included any code, I can only presume you are not defining the function before using the function or you are defining the function incorrectly.
It is best to provide the code, not merely the error message.

Comment: thank you Daniel - Calling the function ExecuteSqlQuery below the function itself was my resolve - for it had to be defined before attempting to invoke that function - hence the reason PowerShell threw an error.